# Compensating for microphone frequency response in FFT

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I'm making an application that displays an FFT of sound data from a microphone. One thing I need to be able to support is calibrating to the frequency response of the microphone, which will be given to the program via a calibration file. The calibration file contains + or - dB values for different frequencies, like this:

```
20 -2.7
50 +0.5
100 +0.7
135 +0.7
190 +1.4
250 +1
370 +0.9
550 +1
700 +0.6
1000 +0.5
1500 +0.4
2000 +0.5
2800 +0.6
2900 +0.4
3000 +0.5
4000 -0.2
4300 -0.2
5600 +0.7
6150 +0.6
12000 +3.5
13000 +3.5
20000 -1.5
```

I can just apply the calibration after the FFT and before displaying it on the screen.

My problem is this: how should I interpolate between those values, which are essentially just select points of the whole frequency response of the microphone? A naive approach might be to define rigid rectangular bands around those points and, for each frequency in an FFT, pick one or another calibration line to apply to that frequency. This would cause visible jumps in the FFT graph, however. Another solution might be to use linear interpolation, but I'm still not sure that's the best way.

Is there a "standard" way to do this, that programs like Smaart or FFT devices do? What would be the best way to generate a continuous curve from those few fixed points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approximate an inverse filter for the frequency response of the microphone response using some method, for example the Wiener or LMS methods, or just go with the naive approach (see comments,) and apply this to the recorded signal before calculating the FFT. If that's not an option, I would go with linearly interpolating the points, as I don't see why this would cause any "visible jumps".

Comment: Thanks. Can this be automated? What do you see as being the main advantages of this approach over just adjusting the FFT output, if the sole purpose of the program was only to display an FFT? It is significantly more complicated.

Comment: Okay, I did my research. It looks like Wiener and LMS require you to have input and output signals of the system. For this, all I have is a frequency response curve, so would using those methods even be feasible? What about just generating an filter kernel from the frequency response using IFFT ([described here](http://www.dspguide.com/CH17.PDF)) and convoluting the signal with that? (this would allow me to use the calibration for non-FFT things, like SPL measurements.)

Comment: @tmandry: That should work, and is more or less the same as what I had thought of as the "naive" approach. I'm not really sure what the advantage over your approach is, other than what you pointed out in your second comment.

Comment: Great, thanks. Though I must ask, why do you consider it naive? :)

Comment: @tmandry: Naive in this case isn't a bad word :) I used not long ago, and saw it referred to as naive somewhere, so I guess it stuck with me.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I knew something to the contrary about the source of the calibration data, or about the likely mechanisms causing the nonlinear response, I'd use linear interpolation between each pair of points.

Comment: If this helps, the calibration is sometimes provided by the microphone manufacturer. Other times it is obtained by "listening" to tones at different frequencies and having the user calibrate the response at each frequency to a known good reading (i.e. the readout from a calibrated SPL meter.)

Comment: Also, a [spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) would probably give smoother results; I hadn't thought of this before. Would you recommend that or not?

Comment: Hopefully, someone with more experience than I will weigh in.  But FWIW, I don't think you'll see the "jumps" that you fear with linear.